# How to convert a sql query to laravel queryBuilder

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have a sql query as follow:

```
SELECT count(as_user_id) as Users,
 CONCAT( HOUR(created_at), ' to ', CONCAT( HOUR(created_at), ':59:59' ) ) as Time_Frame
FROM content_impression
WHERE created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY 
 DATE(created_at), 
 HOUR(created_at)
ORDER BY count(as_user_id) DESC
```

The result of the query is:

Users | Time_Frame

- 2 | 10 to 10:59:59
- 2 | 9 to 9:59:59
- 1 | 11 to 11:59:59
- 1 | 12 to 12:59:59

I want to convert to eloquent query.

I have tried as like,

```
$results = DB::table("content_impression")
        ->select(DB::raw(" count(as_user_id) as Users,CONCAT( HOUR(created_at), ' to ', CONCAT( HOUR(created_at), ':59:59' ) ) as Time_Frame"))
        ->whereRaw("created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY")
        ->groupByRaw("DATE(created_at),HOUR(created_at)")->orderByRaw("count(as_user_id) DESC")->get();
```

the error is occurred like below;

[image]

Comment: After diggin around multiple stackoverflow questions and answers this is what I came up with:
`$results = DB::table("as_journey_content_impression")->select(DB::raw("count(as_user_id) as Users", "CONCAT( HOUR(created_at), ' to ', CONCAT(HOUR(created_at), ':59:59') as Time_Frame"))->whereBetween('created_at',array(Carbon::now(), Carbon::now()->subDays(1))->groupBy([DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'),DB::raw('HOUR(created_at)')])->orderBy('Users','desc')->get();`

Comment: Here are listed links helping with this issue: [whereBetween](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824624/laravel-q-where-between-dates) [subDays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33361628/how-to-query-between-two-dates-using-laravel-and-eloquent) [CONCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306178/laravel-querybuilder-with-join-and-concat) [Select count and groupBy](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-select-with-count-query-with-group-by-exampleexample.html)

Comment: The error itself is not related to querybuilder but rather with laravel/database configuration.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145384/how-to-disable-only-full-group-by-option-in-laravel) for this error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

1. Use `where('created_at','>=',now()->subDay(1))` instead of `whereRaw("created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY")`.
2. Use `groupBy('Time_Frame')` since the error is telling you to `groupBy` the columns you **selected** which is named as `Time_frame` **not** `DATE(created_at),HOUR(created_at)`.
3. Use `latest('Users')` instead of `orderByRaw("count(as_user_id) DESC")` and use the alias you defind (`Users`) inside the `orderBy` not `count(as_user_id)`.

```
$results = DB::table("content_impression")
               ->selectRaw(" count(as_user_id) as Users,CONCAT( Hour(created_at), ' to ', CONCAT( Hour(created_at), ':59:59' ) ) as Time_Frame")
               ->where('created_at','>=',now()->subDay(1))
               ->groupBy('Time_Frame')->latest('Users')->get();
```